# what is the pvrtc texture compression binary format?

Tags: compression, textures, pvrtc

I'm not looking for a definition. I'm looking for what the format is so I make them or decode them myself, no libraries, no tools, just the format so I can write my own code. If you know what the format is please post it here or post a link.

Answer (score 1):

According to a colleague of mine, the PowerVR SDK from Imagination Technologies should contain reference decompression code and also a document ("PVRTC & Texture Compression
User Guide") with the binary format.

Comment: Some of the format information is given in the original "Graphics Hardware 2003" paper: http://www.imgtec.com/powervr/insider/docs/PVRTextureCompression.pdf

Comment: 2003 paper at Graphics Hardware: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.61.7956